# C++ OpenCV HOG at location from Cache

Tags: c++, opencv, caching, machine-learning, computer-vision

I want to extract HOG features using the OpenCV Module. I just want the features, not the whole svm detection process.

To speed up things, I would like to use the HOGCache object.

My question: is this possible to use the HOGCache on a specified zone of the image, and then call the HOG compute method (or a changed version, I guess) to extract the HOG vector at a specified location ?

The HOG compute has to be called at several locations, and not using the cache gives me a really slow process.

I guess this is possible since the svm detector use the cache, but with a a sliding window.

Thx for your help